# Автоматизация процесса создания новых колонок в dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

У меня есть датафрейм, мне необходимо из каждого значения первой колонки вычесть первое значение второй колонки и записать результат этого действия новую колонку, и так далее пока значения во второй колонке не закончатся.
Ниже я написал пример кода, который выполняет то что мне нужно, но только c первым и вторым фиксированным значением значением из **column_1**
 `column_1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
column_2 <- c(6,7,8,9,10)

 df <-data.frame(column_1, column_2)
df$column_3 <- df$column_2-df$column_1[1]
df$column_4 <- df$column_2-df$column_1[2]`

Мне нужно проделать эту операцию с каждым значением **column_1** по отдельности, в конкретно этом датафрейме **df** мне необходимо получить 5 новых колонок с данными.

Я хочу автоматизировать этот процесс, чтобы для каждого значения **column_1** не писать номер элемента к которому я обращаюсь, но пока не знаю как.

Comment: а как вы уже пробовали решать?

Comment: Я понимаю как сделать одну новую колонку '> column_1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
                                                                          > column_2 <- c(6,7,8,9,10)                                  
                                                                          > data.frame <- c(column_1, column_2)                                   
                                                                          > df$column_3 <- df$column_2-df$column_1[1]          Но как сделать много новых колонок пока не могу понять, возможно через цикл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это похоже на задачи про генерацию чисел Фибоначчи.

```
my_function <- function(n){
    df <-data.frame(V1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                    V2 = c(6,7,8,9,10))
    sapply(3:n, function(x){
      df[,x] <<- df[,1]+df[x-2,2]
    })
    return(df)}

  my_function(5)
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  6  7  8  9
2  2  7  8  9 10
3  3  8  9 10 11
4  4  9 10 11 12
5  5 10 11 12 13
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, это почти то, что нужно, только в Вашем варианте правильно посчитан только **df$V3**, а **df$V4** насколько я понял является результатом **df$V2+df$V3**, а мне нужно, чтобы в **df$V4** был записан результат **df$V1+df$V2[2]**, то есть математические действия происходят только со значениями **df$V1** и **df$V2**, а результат записывается в новую колонку.

Comment: Исправил ответ.